# Laravel love package installation failing

Tags: laravel

I am trying to install the taliptako/laravel-love package but it keeps bringing me this error I don't know why. I have been on this over since yesterday and now thank God I find a place where I can be helped.

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - taliptako/laravel-love 5.3 requires illuminate/database ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~5.7.0|~5.8.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/database[5.5.x-dev, 5.6.x-dev, 5.7.17, 5.7.18, 5.7.19, 5.7.x-dev, 5.8.x-dev, v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2, v5.5.28, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.35, v5.5.36, v5.5.37, v5.5.39, v5.5.40, v5.5.41, v5.5.43, v5.5.44, v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22, v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.25, v5.6.26, v5.6.27, v5.6.28, v5.6.29, v5.6.3, v5.6.30, v5.6.31, v5.6.32, v5.6.33, v5.6.34, v5.6.35, v5.6.36, v5.6.37, v5.6.38, v5.6.39, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9, v5.7.0, v5.7.1, v5.7.10, v5.7.11, v5.7.15, v5.7.2, v5.7.20, v5.7.21, v5.7.22, v5.7.23, v5.7.26, v5.7.27, v5.7.28, v5.7.3, v5.7.4, v5.7.5, v5.7.6, v5.7.7, v5.7.8, v5.7.9, v5.8.0, v5.8.11, v5.8.12, v5.8.14, v5.8.15, v5.8.17, v5.8.18, v5.8.19, v5.8.2, v5.8.20, v5.8.22, v5.8.24, v5.8.27, v5.8.28, v5.8.29, v5.8.3, v5.8.30, v5.8.31, v5.8.32, v5.8.33, v5.8.34, v5.8.35, v5.8.36, v5.8.4, v5.8.8, v5.8.9].
    - taliptako/laravel-love v5.x-dev requires illuminate/database ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~5.7.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/database[5.5.x-dev, 5.6.x-dev, 5.7.17, 5.7.18, 5.7.19, 5.7.x-dev, v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2, v5.5.28, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.35, v5.5.36, v5.5.37, v5.5.39, v5.5.40, v5.5.41, v5.5.43, v5.5.44, v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22, v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.25, v5.6.26, v5.6.27, v5.6.28, v5.6.29, v5.6.3, v5.6.30, v5.6.31, v5.6.32, v5.6.33, v5.6.34, v5.6.35, v5.6.36, v5.6.37, v5.6.38, v5.6.39, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9, v5.7.0, v5.7.1, v5.7.10, v5.7.11, v5.7.15, v5.7.2, v5.7.20, v5.7.21, v5.7.22, v5.7.23, v5.7.26, v5.7.27, v5.7.28, v5.7.3, v5.7.4, v5.7.5, v5.7.6, v5.7.7, v5.7.8, v5.7.9].
    - don't install illuminate/database 5.7.17|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/database 5.7.18|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/database 5.7.19|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/database 5.7.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/database 5.8.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.7.0|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.7.1|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.7.10|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.7.11|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.7.15|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.7.2|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.7.20|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.7.21|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.7.22|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.7.23|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.7.26|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.7.27|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.7.28|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.7.3|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.7.4|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.7.5|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.7.6|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.7.7|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.7.8|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.7.9|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.8.0|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.8.11|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.8.12|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.8.14|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.8.15|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.8.17|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.8.18|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.8.19|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.8.2|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.8.20|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.8.22|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.8.24|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.8.27|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.8.28|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.8.29|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.8.3|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.8.30|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.8.31|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.8.32|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.8.33|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.8.34|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.8.35|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.8.36|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.8.4|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.8.8|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.8.9|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/database 5.5.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/database 5.6.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.5.0|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.5.16|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.5.17|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.5.2|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.5.28|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.5.33|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.5.34|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.5.35|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.5.36|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.5.37|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.5.39|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.5.40|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.5.41|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.5.43|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.5.44|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.6.0|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.6.1|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.6.10|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.6.11|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.6.12|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.6.13|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.6.14|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.6.15|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.6.16|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.6.17|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.6.19|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.6.2|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.6.20|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.6.21|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.6.22|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.6.23|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.6.24|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.6.25|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.6.26|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.6.27|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.6.28|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.6.29|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.6.3|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.6.30|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.6.31|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.6.32|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.6.33|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.6.34|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.6.35|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.6.36|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.6.37|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.6.38|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.6.39|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.6.4|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.6.5|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.6.6|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.6.7|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.6.8|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.6.9|don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0
    - Installation request for laravel/framework (locked at v8.6.0, required as ^8.0) -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v8.6.0].
    - Installation request for taliptako/laravel-love ^5.3 -> satisfiable by taliptako/laravel-love[5.3, v5.x-dev].
```

I am still new here and am learning laravel so if anyone could assist it  will be very pleasing

Comment: Probably because the package is not compatible with laravel 8?

Comment: So what might be the solution

Comment: The solution is, you need to be wait for a compitable version for Laravel 8.x  https://laravel-love.readme.io/docs/system-requirements

Comment: You can use the original package `cybercog/laravel-love` that is compatible with Laravel 8